# Generate SNMP traps with PHP

Tags: php, snmp, snmp-trap

I'm desperately searching for a way to generate SNMP traps from PHP. I know the build in methods to use snmpget but I was not able to figure out how to send SNMP traps.

Does anybody know a class / code snippet for it? Searching the web did not bring up anything other than using exec to call cli tools which is definately no option for me.

I suspect that it would be neccessary to use socket_create and corresponding functionality to generate the UDP package manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody searching for such a library these days (in 2019), I found https://github.com/FreeDSx/SNMP which supports sending SNMPv1 and SNMPv2 traps (including inform requests).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no native way for generating traps/informs with php. Even the SNMP extension only permits get and set requests. So the only (quick) way to accomplish this is to call an external tool like net-snmp. The proper command line would be something like

```
snmptrap -v 1 -c public manager enterprises.spider test-hub 3 0 '' interfaces.iftable.ifentry.ifindex.1 i 1
```

will send a generic linkUp trap to manager, for interface 1 (taken from the [manpage](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmptrap.html)). To execute this from php the net-snmp binaries should be on the path of the system and you could either call [exec](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php), [shell_exec](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php) or [proc_open](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.proc-open.php).

Obvisouly you also can send the trap by yourself by encoding it as raw byte array and sending it over an UDP socket, but then you had to implement a BER encoder and a SNMP packet encoder all by yourself which I don't recommend. For your reference, you would need those informations:

- [Basic Encoding Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Encoding_Rules)
- [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1)
- and some further [links found
  here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNMP)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but using an external program is definately no option. I'll check the links you gave in your answer and try it my self.

Answer (score 3):

There are no core SNMP trap libraries. Or even any core libraries that will help you package an SNMP udp packet. I did however find this abandoned project. http://code.google.com/p/php-snmp/ which provides most of what you would need to send a simple trap.

A little more active but a lot more complex seems to be http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/snmpts/php/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just came across it via Google, and thought to update it according to my findings in case someone else also lands here.
As Jek answered, using net-snmp is the best solution.
Although the original post said  that he didn't want to use any external components, consider you can now add net-snmp though apt-get (look up package php-snmp) for many Linux distro's, and I'm sure installing on Windows will be equally easy.
The great benefit of using it, is as of PHP 5.3.3, PHP inherintly has built-in interface functions to use SNMP, so that you don't have to use exec, shell_exec or proc_open. Everything can be done in a PHP environment.
See http://php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but I was well aware of this functionality in PHP. I was - and still am - searching for a method to send SNMP Traps. Using SNMP GET/SET is not what I need. Sorry